# Bitrix: Выгрузка списка элементов инфоблока в Excel

Tags: битрикс

В панели над списком элементов инфоблока на сайте есть кнопка с "Export Excel" - проблема в том, что она выгружает html-таблицу с данными элементов. Возможно ли как-то изменить это поведение? Я недавно занимаюсь Битрикс и пока не представляю, где меняется поведение этой кнопки. Что скажете?

**Обновление**

Небольшое уточнение - экспортируется текстовый html файл с расширением *.xls . Создается ощущение, что функция экспорта задумана, но не доделана, так как не создается правильная структура документа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем конечно может не все сразу у меня получилось немного еще отлучался в процессе записи видео так что ві там пропускайте где буду долго стоять, прям мастер класс не получился, но сама суть в моем видео присутсвует и я полностью реализовал ваш функционал который вы хотите, можете посмотреть в видео и кнопку и выгрузку в Excel по кнопке, оно не будет переходить на отдельную страницу это у меня так получилось т.к. были ошибки, а сразу выдавать файл.

https://youtu.be/kGcy_6nLpF0

Comment: видео обработалось можете смотреть, единственное подождите пока его в hd конвертирует.

Comment: Спасибо! Многое прояснилось.

Answer (score 2):

1. Да данная кнопка создает html таблицу.
2. Да Excel читает данную таблицу как свою.
3. Для создания именно Excel файла придется воспользоватся phpExcel расширением. Навесится на событие OnAdminListDisplay и добаивть свою кнопку.

Comment: В том то и дело, что excel не воспринимает эту html таблицу как "свою" =) вместо этого, он просто расставляет теги в ячейки на листе. Событие OnAdminListDisplay находится где-то внутри компонента или в шаблоне?

Comment: Хм, у меня openoffice и открыл данный файл как свой. Попробуте изменить расширение на xslx хотя, если уж пользуетесь битрикс, значит есть у вас техподдержка, напишите им и я думаю они решат ваш вопрос сами платная же система. Но принципиально если хотите свою кнопку - сделайте ее.

Comment: Было бы неплохо сделать свою кнопку, но во-первых, я пока не нашел способа это сделать (где и что  менять в компоненте), а во-вторых, было бы идеально использовать шаблон экселевского файла, чтобы можно было выводить отчет в форматированном виде. Для этого, насколько я понял, можно попробовать предложенный phpExcel .

Comment: Вам рассказать как это сделать?

Comment: Если не затруднит. Я не нашел в документации с чего начать в данном направлении, а битриксовый форум молчит.

Comment: Ок, сейчас сформирую в ответе.